# getting undefined error on textbox data load (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am trying to pre-populate textbox. I am using the web api call for it and my service call is working fine but when I tried load to data on textbox I am getting following error.

```
customer.component.html: caused by: Cannot read 
property 'firstName' of undefined
Error: Error in app/customers/customer.component.html:18:31 caused by: 
Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

After page load completed, I checked customer.firstName value on button click but there it is showing correct value. Not sure why I am getting error on initial page load.

customer.component.html

```
<input id="firstNameId" type="text" [(ngModel)] = customer.firstName 
  name="firstName" #firstNameVar="ngModel" />
```

CustomerComponent

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
   customer: ICustomer;
   errorMessage: string;
   constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute, 
            private customerService :CustomerService){
   }
   ngOnInit(): void {
     this._route.params.subscribe(
        pa => {
            this.getPerson();
      });
    }
   getPerson() {
    this.customerService.getCustomer()
    .subscribe(
            (cust:ICustomer) =>
            {
                this.customer = cust;
            },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    )
   }
 }
```

Customer Interface

```
 export interface ICustomer {
    firstName:string,
    lastName:string,
    email:string
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use safe operator to check if the value is present  **`customer?.firstName`**

```
<input id="firstNameId" type="text" [(ngModel)] = customer?.firstName 
  name="firstName" #firstNameVar="ngModel" />
```

Comment: After page load completed, I checked customer.firstName value on button click, it is showing correct value. Not sure why I am getting  undefine error on initial page load.

Comment: it has to wait until the data is being retrieved, you can handle that as above. did it work?

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. Am I suppose to use other life cycle hook other than onInit for this kind of situation ? If so which one is best for this kind of situation ?

Comment: No you can use onInit, and i am sure this should work. what is the exact error you are getting

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in customer.component.html:9:52 caused by: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
Error: Error in app/customer.component.html:9:52 caused by: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Comment: can you clear cache after adding the above answer and check

Answer (score 1):

You are just defining the customer object instead you should initialize the object with required properties like below:

```
customer: ICustomer = {
  firstName: null
};
```

[Demo with explicit assignment](https://plnkr.co/edit/0NHhco?p=preview)

Or you can use class instead of interface to define a model for customer and initalize the properties like below:

```
export class App implements OnInit {
  customer:Customer;
  constructor() {
    this.customer = new Customer('Anil','Nani','anil@nani.com')
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[Demo with class](https://plnkr.co/edit/G0gFQa?p=preview)